# Navigating (Cruddy)HTTPS site with CURL

Tags: curl, https

I am trying to navigate an HTTPS page using cURL. My problem isn't with cURL per say though, it's with the page in general. The problem is that after I am logged in, I want to go to a certain page so that I can collect some information. However, when I try to directly go to the URL, the site automatically logs me out. This is not just through cURL but also happens when I use a web browser. The only way to get to the page I want is by clicking on the hyperlink on the site (Which seems to just be a redirection to the URL I've been putting in). I've explored cookies and sessions (Session ID seems to change whenever I change pages?) to no avail. I can't seem to find any Javascript that is running and affecting the "click" nor can I find any secret POST fields so my question is:

Is there a commonly known way that the server can "know" whether I've navigated there through the URL versus a hyperlink?
Does it have something to do with it being HTTPS?

I am new to web programming stuff, so I had figured that the hyperlink was more or less just a shortcut for inputting the URL yourself.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

The site was looking for a 'Referer' request in the header. If anyone has problems like this, the HttpFox add on for FireFox is EXTREMELY helpful. It will log all POST, and headers sent & received by you. Then all you need to do is navigate on the browser and spoof what occurs in cURL.